# Не выполняется запрос MySQL? подскажите в чем проблема.

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM blog WHERE Kategorie IN (4)
```

Вот что в базе - http://joxi.ru/xAeJKYYuMEPGry Выводит 0 записей почему то....

Если

```
SELECT * FROM blog WHERE Kategorie IN (4,5)
```

Выводит две записи ID которых - 17 и 18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разумеется,

> SELECT * FROM blog WHERE Kategorie IN
> (4)

Вывести все записи в которых Kategorie = 4, у вас таких нет.

Как я понимаю вы пытаетесь сделать возможность выбора нескольких категорий, самый простой способ сделать еще одну табличку:

```
 category_id post_id
```

А далее цеплять уже подзапросом:

```
SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id IN (SELECT post_id FROM categories WHERE category_id IN (4, 5, 6, 7));
```

Или join`ом:

```
  SELECT * FROM categories c
  LEFT JOIN blog b ON b.id = c.post_id
  WHERE category_id IN (4, 5, 6, 7);
```

Comment: спасибо, а что лучше подзапрос использовать или JOIN ?

Comment: Я бы использовал join, а вообще, погуглите, почитайте

Comment: сделал, так как вы порекомендовали, все сработало, НО!!! Мне нужно выбрать посты на которые подписан пользователь (категории), при этом методе он дублирует вывод сообщений.

Т.е. если пост принадлежит категории 4 и 5, и пользователь подписан на них, то запрос выводит два раза эту запись, а надо один.

Comment: Почитайте о JOIN`ах.

Answer (score 0):

```
Kategorie RLIKE '(^|,)4(,|$)'
```

так должно сработать

Comment: Божественно, а потом сайт грузится 10 секунд

Comment: все зависит от ситуации где это используют. Если записей в таблице не много, то можно так